# RAM, CPU and Task Manager?

Tags: memory

1. The usage of CPU keeps fluctuating in Task Manager from 5% to 100%, is it normal? I just replaced my DDR3 2GB with DDR3 4GB RAM, or is this replacement is cause??
2. In the memory tab it shows cached 1.6GB, How can i reduce it??
3. What does this committed memory represents in Task Manager?

Additional information:
OS- Window 10

CPU- intel celeron N3060

RAM- DDR3 4GB(present)

Laptop- Dell inspiron 15-3552 (mfg 2017)

**EDIT-** My CPU usages goes to (70-80)% just by hovering a cursor over task manager and desktop. when I checked the application which is using much RAM, it shows 64-bit synaptics pointing service(i.e. my touchpad) 33% and Task manager 40%. When I stop hovering to goes back to normal like 4-5%. If I open firefox browser, it sticks to 100% and If I keep everything in normal(i.e. if i don't touch anything), it again goes back to normal. My computer doesnot lags in any cases. RAM usages is normal(28-50%).
I have changed many settings in window, so I thought, I messed up with window settings. so, i formatted my hard-disk and installed window 10 pro but this doesnot solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, it's normal for your CPU to be used by the programs on the computer. The amount of cached RAM depends on the programs you're using and indicate no issue. Why do you wish to decrease the cache?

Comment: I understand about the cache and it needs to be there for window successful operation but the usage of CPU does not seems to be normal because when I log on, it uses 3-5% only but when i move the cursor, it goes to 70-80%. And when I open firefox it sticks to 100%. Do you think, it is still normal?

Comment: Why is that information not in the body of the question? It appears to me to be very relevant to making your question less broad and more answerable. However, you'll need to do more sleuthing to see WHAT processes are spiking when your mouse moves, and whether resetting FF or disabling plugins results in lower CPU, because simply adding what you have mentioned in the above comment is still not giving us very much information to go on, even if it is better than before. Basically, we only know what you tell us. So the more you tell us, the more we know and the better our answers may be.

Comment: My CPU usages goes to (70-80)% just by hovering a cursor over desktop, Task manager shows 64-bit synaptics pointing service(i.e. my touchpad) 33% and Task manager 40%. When I stop hovering to goes back to normal like 4-5%. while using firefox, it sticks to 100% and if i don't touch anything, it again goes back to normal. My computer doesnot lags in any cases. RAM usages is normal(28-50%).
I have changed many settings in window, so I thought, I messed up with window settings. so, i formatted my hard-disk and installed window 10 pro but this doesnot solve my problem.

Comment: [This](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2017/09/05/hey-synaptics-can-you-please-stop-polling/) might be relevant. It seems the Synaptic driver has been known for high CPU usage. On a dual core like the Celeron N3060 that driver's CPU load would represent a higher proportion of the CPU's total resources and therefore result in a higher CPU % in Task Manager. This does not seem to be memory related, unless the touchpad driver behaves differently when less system RAM is available.

Comment: Last question is: what worse it will be if i keep using my laptop with 100% cpu usage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is good, but I want to put emphasis on this part:

> 2. In the memory tab it shows cached 1.6GB, How can I reduce it??

You don't want to reduce it. Unused RAM is wasted RAM. If RAM is unused by software, Windows will use it for cache, ie. temporary storage of stuff for high-performance access. This feature is useful because RAM is way, way faster than disks, even SSDs. When programs need more RAM, Windows will decide which cached stuff is least useful and remove it from cache, reclaiming some RAM to be used by programs. So caching has no drawbacks, but gives you performance benefits and uses RAM that would otherwise be wasted.

Comment: I do understand about cache. But my cpu usage doesnot seems to be normal. I tried unstalling dell touchpad driver as suggested by other superuser but it doesnot help me. The actual problem that I have noticed is when I turn ON my Laptop everything seems to be normal. When I open task manager and hover over it, it goes to 40%+ and when I stop hovering over it, it again goes down to 8-9% only. I un-installed dell touchpad and have no gesture in use, but it still doesnot help wih the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> when i move the cursor, it goes to 70-80%

Are you using a USB-based monitor?  USB utilizes the CPU heavily.  A display solution that doesn't rely on USB will be better.  If you have "DisplayLink" software installed, the DisplayLink driver may still be hooked in and reacting to screen changes.

Remote access software might also cause this.

Also a mouse driver certainly may do this too, especially if things like gesture detection are enabled.  If you don't use gesture detection, etc. from your mouse, you can probably uninstall the touchpad or mouse driver and simply rely on Windows base PS/2 or USB mouse support.

Update: You may want to look at this https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Touchpad-causing-too-high-CPU-usage-on-Vostro-3558-Windows-10/td-p/5031967

> the memory tab it shows cached 1.6GB

This is probably cached disk.  Windows uses unused RAM as cache for stuff it reads from disk.  If it needs the RAM for other purposes it evicts this cache and goes back to the disk.  There's no need to worry about this.

> What does this committed memory represents in Task Manager?

Resource Monitor is far better for seeing what's going on with your system than Task Manager.

Comment: My cpu usage doesnot seems to be normal. I tried unstalling dell touchpad driver as suggested but it doesnot help me. The actual problem that I have noticed is when I turn ON my Laptop everything seems to be normal. When I open task manager and hover over it, it goes to 40%+ and when I stop hovering over it, it again goes down to 8-9% only. I un-installed dell touchpad and have no gesture in use, but it still doesnot help wih the issue?